# Is R-CNN fine-tuning the whole network or only the pool5, fc6 and fc7 layer?

Tags: deep-learning

Is R-CNN fine-tuning the whole network or only the pool5, fc6 and fc7 layer?
Moreover, how can a network back-propagation through the pooling layer?